# ssh-agent reset in Windows Subsystem for linux (WSL)

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I am trying to use ssh-agent under WSL but the SSH params are wiped after the script is run

From .bashrc (cut down version)

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add

ssh-add -l
echo "SSH_AGENT_PID is" $SSH_AGENT_PID
echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is" $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Prompts for the passphrase then shows the fingerprint and relevant variables

straight after at prompt (or seperate script) running

```
ssh-add -l
echo "SSH_AGENT_PID is" $SSH_AGENT_PID
echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is" $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

gives

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
SSH_AGENT_PID is
SSH_AUTH_SOCK is
```

(tidied for readability)

the agent is still running with the original pid (checked in top)
also tried `eval $(ssh-agent ) > /dev/null` and `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` and in combination

Why do these get wiped? ssh-agent worked fine until windows update 1709 "fall creators update"

for info:
linux version 4.4.0-43-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm copying the answer given in another similar thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942800/9966057).

It's no use trying to tweak your session setup.

Full answer : https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183

Short version : ssh-agent forwarding is broken by a getsockopt bug in wsl / ubuntu 18.04 (or any other linux I would imagine).

Comment: You answered perfectly. Providing a link is great, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259), which you did.

Comment: Yes, if you copy information written by somebody else, you must link to the source; see [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing "").

Answer (score 10):

Try to add the `-s` parameter, like in :

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

This parameter is [described](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) as :

> **-s** Generate Bourne shell commands on stdout. This is the default if SHELL does not look like it's a csh style of shell.

Comment: Tried in both the `> dev`...  and simple versions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to forward ssh keys from WSL2 to a linux server by using `keychain` as described in this post https://esc.sh/blog/ssh-agent-windows10-wsl2/

```
Install keychain

sudo apt-get install keychain
Edit your ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc or whatever rc file that corresponds to your weird shell of choice (I’m not judging you) and add the following to the bottom of your file.

# For Loading the SSH key
/usr/bin/keychain -q --nogui $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
source $HOME/.keychain/$HOST-sh
```

I was following this guide https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding but I was not able to make it work.

Before using keychain this `echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` was returning empty in the server.